# need support with count formula excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am hoping someone can tell me where I am going wrong in the formula in cells in column L.

I want it to count in a series order the amount of sales each person does.
If a status says 14DMb, it should not count as this is a cancellation. the cells that say value do not work.

This formula works in cell L3  `=COUNTIFS($K$4,K4:K4,$M$4,"=sale")`

The cell below I used the formula below but it comes up as value. 
`=COUNTIFS($K$4,K4:K5,$M$4:$M$5,"=sale")`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your order is wrong in the first and second criteria:

Put this in L3 and copy down:

```
=COUNTIFS($K$3:K3,K3,$M$3:M3,"Sale")
```

Comment: Scott, that is amazing thank you so much. I don't fully understand it but that was perfect.